# Create a table with all the columns of inner join of two other tables without copying data

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables `Table1` and `Table2` with `10,000` and `15,000` rows each. I want to create a table `Table3` that can contain all the data of inner join of `Table1` and `Table2`, yet is **empty**. I tried something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table3
(LIKE Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.col11 = Table2.col21);
```

What is the best solution I can have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE your_table AS your_select WITH NO DATA;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html